# How Get All duplicate record using linq

Tags: asp.net, linq

In my project I'm having a critical problem: I have a collection of all `Employee`s in a collection. Some of the `Employee`s have the same `LName`:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string MName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public char Gender { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public List<Employee> GetAll()
    {
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 1,
            FName = "John",
            MName = "",
            LName = "Shields",
            DOB = DateTime.Parse("12/11/1971"),
            Gender = 'M'
        });
        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 2,
            FName = "Mary",
            MName = "Matthew",
            LName = "Jacobs",
            DOB = DateTime.Parse("01/17/1961"),
            Gender = 'F'
        });
        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 3,
            FName = "Amber",
            MName = "Carl",
            LName = "Agar",
            DOB = DateTime.Parse("12/23/1971"),
            Gender = 'M'
        });
        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 4,
            FName = "Kathy",
            MName = "",
            LName = "Foxsss",
            DOB = DateTime.Parse("11/15/1976"),
            Gender = 'F'
        });
        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 5,
            FName = "Lena",
            MName = "Ashco",
            LName = "Bilton",
            DOB = DateTime.Parse("05/11/1978"),
            Gender = 'F'
        });
        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 6,
            FName = "Susanne",
            MName = "",
            LName = "Buck",
            DOB = DateTime.Parse("03/7/1965"),
            Gender = 'F'
        });
        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 7,
            FName = "Jim",
            MName = "",
            LName = "Hooks",
            DOB = DateTime.Parse("09/11/1972"),
            Gender = 'M'
        });
        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 8,
            FName = "Jane",
            MName = "G",
            LName = "Hooks",
            DOB = DateTime.Parse("12/11/1972"),
            Gender = 'F'
        });
        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 9,
            FName = "Robert",
            MName = "",
            LName = "Fox",
            DOB = DateTime.Parse("06/28/1964"),
            Gender = 'M'
        });
        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {
            ID = 10,
            FName = "Cindy",
            MName = "Preston",
            LName = "Fox",
            DOB = DateTime.Parse("01/11/1978"),
            Gender = 'M'
        });

        return empList;
    }
}
```

How can I get the duplicate records (based on `LName`) from my collection using LINQ?

Comment: You should read about [Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx). Also, when using object initializers, the parentheses are redundant :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear, but looks like you're looking for following:

```
var duplicates = GetAll().GroupBy(x => x.LName)
                         .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                         .SelectMany(g => g)
                         .ToList()
```

It groups element by `LName`, takes only groups that have more than 1 element and returns them as a list.

`duplicates` will be `List<Employee>`.

You can make it a bit better using `ToDictionary` instead of `ToList`:

```
var duplicates = GetAll().GroupBy(x => x.LName)
                         .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                         .ToDictionary(g = > g.Key, g.ToList());
```

It will be `Dictionary<string, List<Employee>>`, with a `LName` as a dictionary key, and list of items with given `LName` as `Value`.

Comment: Why not `.ToLookup(g = > g.Key)`? Seems a lot cleaner than `.ToDictionary(g = > g.Key, g.ToList())`

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yes, it could be a lookup :)

Comment: @p.s.w.g sorry for that but when i use .ToLookup(g = > g.Key) then it will give me distinct duplicate record but i wont all duplicate record not distinct.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do a full count for a given key; you can actually be a little more efficient and still clearly express what it means for there to be a duplicate. To check for duplicates, you merely need to check that after you *skip* the first item, see if there are *any* remaining:

```
var duplicates = GetAll().GroupBy(x => x.LName)
                         .Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any())
                         .SelectMany(g => g);
```

You can convert this to a list if you need with `ToList`. Or you can say:

```
var duplicates = GetAll().GroupBy(x => x.LName)
                         .Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any())
                         .ToLookup(g => g.Key);
```

to have them collected by `Employee.LName`.